# How to keep color for <a> after click

Tags: html, css

I have 3 `<a>` tag link to 3 pages. I set `hover` state is `red` and now I want after I click and go to a pages will keep `background-color` of this `<a>` like `hover`state.How can i do it?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ulimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" class = "active">Home</a>
            <a href="team.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
        //some  code here
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
header > nav > a{
    background-color:while;
}
header > nav > a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 204, 164);
}
```

I mean after I click to `Teams` will change background-color of Teams like hover state

Comment: you need some javascript

Comment: @Stack I've deleted my answer because it doesn't reflect what you want. 

You need to change your question to clarify that you want is to have the 'current active page' be styled differently. ie. when you click 'home' again presumably you want to the color to change back.

Comment: Basically it looks like what you want to do is remove the `active` class from the 'Home' link and ad it to the 'team' link. How you do that depends on what you're using to generate this HTML.

Comment: yep, I want change background color of 'current active page'. But dont use js, only css.

Comment: can you visit my drive link, it have some image template https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C4WD_Wvhcm_hyDRoUENXd34NH-U__Kq_?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear about what technology you are using, but on the face of what you would do is have three seperate pages (index.html, teams.html, history.html).

Each of these would share the boilerplate you have here, but change which link has the 'active class'.

Eg.

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ulimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" class = "active">Home</a>
            <a href="team.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
        //some  code here
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

teams.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - Teams</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ulimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html" >Home</a>
            <a href="team.html" class = "active">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html">History</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
        //some  code here
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

history.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - History</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ulimate Frisbee</h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="team.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html"  class = "active">History</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
<main>
        //some  code here
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

You then use the `.active` class to style that way.

eg

```
a:hover, a.active {
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Now, copy pasting code like this probably isn't sustainable, so that's where you might start using a templating enging like [pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), or be doing some kind of backend rendering or whatever.

But this is the gyst of it.

Comment: yep, this code above is code in index.html.But the other 2 pages also have the same header and access hw1.css

Comment: @Stack so you will need to edit those files to change the class on the linsk.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you very well, can you explain?

Comment: @Stack have you seen how in my code I have changed the class on the `<a>` elements?

Comment: yep, sorry about that, because my duty to edit the CSS and can not edit HTML, I try to find another way

Comment: @Stack Ok. You need to be clear about this stuff in your question. 'I need to achieve this without modifying the HTML, and without using javascript'. 

AFAIK it's not possible. Makes for an interesting question.

Comment: This also a great way, thank you so much, i will fix it